# Why isn't it working on Android when I tap the notification that was pushed from Firebase in Flutter, but it's working fine on iOS?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

## Main problem

I've been trying to find a solution for a few days, but haven't had any luck yet. I've already checked the permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml** and tested on both real devices and emulators/simulators, but it's still not working on Android. It only works on iOS.

## My code

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (kReleaseMode) {
    debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) {};
  }

  //Firebase Core
  FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    // Handle notification when the app is in the background, and the user taps on it
    await _showNotificationDialog(
      context: navigatorkey.currentState!.overlay!.context,
      title: message.notification?.title ?? "Notification",
      body: message.notification?.body ?? "Notification body",
    );
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (message.notification != null) {
    // Handle notification when the app is terminated
    await _showNotificationDialog(
      context: navigatorkey.currentState!.overlay!.context,
      title: message.notification?.title ?? "",
      body: message.notification?.body ?? "",
    );
  }
}

Future<void> _showNotificationDialog({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String title,
  required String body,
}) async {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title!),
        content: Text(body!),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('OK'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

## What I want

I want my code to perform the following actions:

1. When a notification is pushed from Firebase, display a dialog box
   when the user taps on the notification.
2. This functionality is currently working on iOS but not on Android.
   Please assist with troubleshooting the Android issue.